# Caculated field in Microsoft Access query suddenly fails on different machine with different data

Tags: ms-access, calculated-columns

In the following query, `calcValB` suddenly started showing `#Error` for all records after changing the data in table. It seems it suddenly cannot recognize `calcValA`.

```
SELECT
  FilePath1,
  cfgVal1 + InStr(Mid(FilePath1, cfgVal1), "\") AS calcValA,
  calcValA + InStr(Mid(FilePath1, calcValA), "\") AS calcValB,
  ...
 FROM
   Table1,
   Config
 WHERE ...
```

Value of `cfgVal1` is 60; `Len(FilePath1)` is always greater than 80; `FilePath1` contains at least one `\` after position 60.

I can work it around using nested queries, but I wonder how this could happen.

What did I try:

- executed the formulas in VBA – they work OK
- recovered all the queries from the backup – errors remain
- tested that the same query works on older copy of tables – it works without error
- teared the expression down to parts that made it obvious that it is `calcValA` which leads to #Error if referenced
- tried to modify the query to make `calcValA = Len(FilePath1)`, `calcValB = calcValA + 5` – this one works
- tried to supply third optional parameter into `Mid()`, set to `999` – still error

My current suspection is that the issue may be with Access running on computers with different locale setting. I am using Slovak and the colleague is using U.S.   I already have seen that in Access, for example form section `Časť1` (Part1) throws error on U.K. locale machines. (The funny thing is that the localized name is put there by default by Access!) But in this case I made sure that the query is 7-bit ASCII only.

**Sample data:**

`Table1.FilePath1` (2 records)

```
a:\a111111\aaaaaa\aaaa\aaaaaaaaaaa\aaaaaa\aaaa aaaaaaa\aa-1\aa\aa1111111\aaaaaaa\aaaaaaa.aaa
a:\a111111\aaaaaa\aaaa\aaaaaaaaaaa\aaaaaa\aaaa aaaaaaa\aa-1\aa\aa1111111\aaaaaaaa\aa1111111.aaaa
```

`Config.cfgVal1` = `61` (there is a single record in the table)

The problm is, the quaery and data work on my machine, they don't work on colleagues' machine.

Comment: Exactly what was change in data? Edit question to show sample data and desired result as text tables.

Comment: @June7 – the question was extended by sample data right after further investigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Compact and Repair the database.

After carrying out **Database Tools** > **Compact and Repair Database** command, the query started working correctly again. Instead of `#Error` values, proper numbers started to appear in `calcValB`.

If you have the source table present in the database as a linked table (from another database), do the same operation with database file which actually contains the table (not only with the database file where the table appears as linked table).

After recovery from such an error, it is a good idea to check whether no records are missing in the table.